# using bootstrap modals with lit-element / web-components

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, lit-element, lit-html

i'm trying to use the modal from bootstrap in my lit-element project.

im using sass to load the bootstrap .scss files seperately. but it doesnt really show the modal on button-click at all. i tried so much, but it doesnt work at all.

**App-Component**

```
import { css, customElement, html, LitElement, property, unsafeCSS } from 'lit-element';
import { router } from '@fhms-wi/router';

const componentCSS = require('./app.component.scss');

@customElement('app-root')
class AppComponent extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`${unsafeCSS(componentCSS)}`;

  ....

firstUpdated() {
    router.subscribe(path => this.requestUpdate());
  }

  renderRouterOutlet() {
    switch (router.getPath()) {
      ...
      case 'spielwiese':
        return html`<app-modal></app-modal>`;
      ...
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <app-header></app-header>
      <app-drawer></app-drawer>
      <div role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
        ${this.renderRouterOutlet()}
      </div>
      `;
  }
```

**App-Component-SCSS**

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss";

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_transitions.scss";
```

**App-Modal-Component**

```
import { css, customElement, html, LitElement, query, property, unsafeCSS } from 'lit-element';

const componentCSS = require('./spielwiese.component.scss');

@customElement('app-modal')
class Spielwiese extends LitElement {
    static styles = css`${unsafeCSS(componentCSS)}`;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return html`        
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}
```

**App-Modal-SCSS**

```
@import "../../index.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_modal.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss";
```

**Webpack Config**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /^\/[a-z]*/, to: '/app/index.html' },]
    },
    publicPath: '/app/',
    port: 9000
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: { loader: 'ts-loader', options: { transpileOnly: true } } },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/, include: /index\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, includePaths: ['./node_modules'] } }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /index\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, includePaths: ['./node_modules'] } }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'fonts/',
              publicPath: '/app/fonts'
            }
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })]
};
```

i also tried to load nearly every single .scss file from the node_modules/bootstrap folder.. but same behavior :(

could you please help me?

Comment: What bundler are you using?

Comment: webpack. updated the post with my webpack config.

Comment: I have a question. How can we import bootstrap to lit element? did you do that?